# Thymeleaf: split string on html tag

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a string containing `<br/>` tag, and I'm trying to split that string on `<br/>`, but I cannot find a way. I tried:

```java
#strings.arraySplit(s, '&lt;br/&gt;')
```

and

```java
#strings.arraySplit(s, '<br/>')
```

Is there a way to split string on html tag in thymeleaf?

Comment: I was a able to split a spring on `<br/>`s with the (first) code you included in your question.  Are you sure you know what is in variable `s` (and that it isn't somehow encoded already)?

Comment: It's not encoded in any way. It's literally something like `some<br/>string<br/>with<br/>break`.

Comment: Well, I'm telling you that what you have worked for me.  I did this: `model.put("test", "test<br />test1");` and in the html: `th:with="pieces=${#strings.arraySplit(test, '&lt;br /&gt;')}"` and `pieces` was an array with 2 elements: `['test', 'test1']`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Maybe it's something with `openhtmltopdf` library, because I'm not seeing multiple rows in pdf. I will investigate further, and thanks again for your time.